# Difference between "sommes", "sont" and "es"

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

I am a beginner and learned that they're all conjugated forms of *être* (to be). I'd like to know which ones I need to use.

Comment: This link might be helpful: http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/etre.php (look in the *présent* section)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verbs in French are much more complicated to conjugate than in English. They change according to the subject, and the tense and modes are more numerous.

*Être* (to be) is among the most complicated because you cannot see the common radical.

- I am = *je suis*
- You are (singular) = *tu es*
- He is = *il est*
- We are = *nous sommes*
- You are (plural/polite form) = *vous êtes*
- They are = *ils sont*

Sites like [leconjugueur](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/) gives you all the forms of a verb according to person, time and tense. [Here](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/%EAtre.html) is the example for *être*, for instance.

When at school, I commonly used the [Bescherelle](http://www.bescherelle.com/), which is still a reference book for conjugation.